# How can I use curl to simulate a request from Firefox over a proxy?

Tags: firefox, curl, https, proxy

In particular, I am attempting to replicate the behavior of firefox when I set it to use a proxy for https traffic.

From my tests, it appears that Firefox sends a CONNECT request to the proxy, while the following curl command directly sends GET to the proxy.

```
curl --proxy-basic mydomain.com:8001 https://www.google.com
```

How can I make curl behave like firefox for testing purposes with respect to the proxy for HTTPS connections?

EDIT1: The issue is not with the User-Agent, because I am not trying to fool the proxy into thinking I am firefox, only to help the proxy function the way it would with Firefox.

Comment: The user-agent is still sent to the server through the proxy, so the server will still see you as not Firefox unless you present yourself as Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this through [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Once you've installed firebug, follow this steps:

1. Right-click a webpage inside firefox and choose this option:

[image]

2. Select `Net` tab

[image]

3. Refresh the page
4. Right-click the URL request you want to simulate
5. Choose `copy as cURL`

[image]

6. The URL request that you want to simulate is now in your clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a proxy otherwise thing would not work, do like:

1. `curl -x 127.0.0.1:8888 "httpS://www.example.com/"` — Be sure that you are trying to connect throught HTTPS, otherwise simple get will be sent.
2. `curl -p -x 127.0.0.1:8888 "http://www.example.com/"` — That thing will work even with ordinary HTTP resources.

Was hard to find any already existing topics on that subject except for this, so maybe I'm answering an already answered question.

Answer (score 0):

Use CURLOPT_USERAGENT option to set the agent to firefox

for example refer 
[The CURL User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194795/the-curl-user-agent)

for handling the ssl part look at this example
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html

The best way to go about it so take a capture in ether real and then set the corresponding header fields using CURLOPT_*

Comment: I don't think it is just the USERAGENT problem. I am more concerned about lack of `CONNECT`.

Comment: @DanielStenberg, the proxy is not seeing the CONNECT though, with the command I gave in the question.

Comment: the command in the question doesn't specify any proxy... see --proxy for that

Answer (score 0):

Ten years later, I now have the requisite knowledge to answer my own question:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=mydomain.com:8001 curl -v https://google.com
```