# How to prevent excessive site visits (suspected screen scraping) from hackers?

Tags: php, security, screen, screen-scraping

I have a website that has been hacked once to have it's database stolen. I think it was done by an automated process that simply accessed the visible website using a series of searches, in the style of 'give me all things beginning with AA', then 'with AB', then 'with AC' and so on. The reality is a little more complicated than this, but that illustrates the principal of the attack. I found the thief and am now taking steps against them, but I want to prevent more like this in the future.

I thought there must be some ready made PHP (which I use) scripts out there. Something that for instance recorded the IP address of the last (say) 50 visitors and tracked the frequency of their requests over the last (say) 5 minutes. It would ban them for (say) 24 hours if they exceeded a certain threshold of requests. However to my amazement I can find no such class, library or example of code intended for this purpose, anywhere online.

Am I missing a trick, or is there a solution here - like the one I imagine, or maybe an even simpler and more effective safeguard?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, can fail2ban do this?

Comment: The obvious solution is captcha. None of the other ideas here could stop me from getting your data (or even slow me down).

Comment: Yeah, captcha's never been defeated. *eyeroll*

Comment: @Jared, good captcha is a deterrent because it costs money to get around it. Blocking ip addresses not so much because free proxies are easy to come by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no silver bullets. If you are trying to brainstorm some possible workarounds and solutions there are none that are particularly easy but here are some things to consider:

- Most screen scrapers will be using `curl` to do their dirty work. There is some discussion such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194795/the-curl-user-agent) on SO about whether trying to block based on User-Agent (or lack thereof) is a good way to prevent screen scrapes. Ultimately, if it helps at all it is probably a good idea (and Google does it to prevent websites from screen scraping them). Because User-Agent spoofing is possible this measure can be overcome fairly easily.
- Log user requests. If you notice an outlier that is far beyond your average number of user requests (up to you to determine what is uneacceptable), then you can serve them an `HTTP 500` error until they revert back to an acceptable range.
- Check number of broken links attempted. If a request to a broken link is served, add it to a log. A few of these should be fine, but it should be pretty clear to find someone who is fishing for data. If they are looking for AA, AB, AC, etc. When that occurs, start to serve `HTTP 500` errors for all of your pages for a set amount of time. You can do this by serving all of your page requests through a Front Controller, or by creating a custom 404-file not found page and redirecting requests there. The 404 page can log them for you.
- Set errors when there is a sudden change in statistics. This is not to shut anyone down, this is just to get you to investigate. The last thing you want to do is shut someone down by accident, because to them it will just seem like the website is down. If you set up a script to send you an e-mail when there has been a sudden change in usage patterns but before you shut someone down, it can help you adjust your decision making appropriately.

These are all fairly broad concepts and there are plenty of other solutions or tweaks on this that can work. In order to do it successfully you will need to monitor your own web patterns in order to determine a safe fix. This is not a small undertaking to craft such a solution (at least not well).

**A Caveat**
This is important: Security is always going to be counterbalanced by useability. If you do it right you won't be sacrificing too much security and your users will never run into these issues. Extensive testing will be important, and because of the nature of websites and downtime being so crucial, perform extensive testing whenever you introduce a new security measure, before bringing it live. Otherwise, you will have a group of very unhappy people to deal with and a potential en mass loss of users. And in the end, screen scraping is probably a better thing to deal with than angry users.

**Another caveat**
This could interfere with SEO for your web page, as search engines like Google employ screen scraping to keep records up to date. Again, the note on balance applies. I am sure there is a fix here that can be figured out but it would stray too far from the original question to look into it.

Comment: Thank you. I have continued to research this question over the last day or two and there really are no easy answers or 'silver bullets' as you put it. Captchas create real usability problems and make normal users hate you. I have looked at rendering some of the text as a.png but then you make Google hate you. It's a minefield. I am going to mark yours as the best answer because you do acknowledge the complexity of this question and give some food for thought in your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Apache, I'd look into `mod_evasive`:

http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442

> mod_evasive is an evasive maneuvers module for Apache to provide
>   evasive action in the event of an HTTP DoS or DDoS attack or brute
>   force attack. It is also designed to be a detection and network
>   management tool, and can be easily configured to talk to ipchains,
>   firewalls, routers, and etcetera. mod_evasive presently reports abuses
>   via email and syslog facilities.

...

"Detection is performed by creating an internal dynamic hash table of
IP Addresses and URIs, and denying any single IP address from any of
the following:

- Requesting the same page more than a few times per second
- Making more than 50 concurrent requests on the same child per second
- Making any requests while temporarily blacklisted (on a blocking list)"

Comment: I find this answer evasive.

Comment: My hosting company doesn't support mod_evasive. A preliminary look around suggests that it seems like only a minority might offer it.