# How to retrieve user_agent data after CURL request in CodeIgniter 2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, http-headers, user-agent

I am trying to access the `$this->agent` object in CodeIgniter 2, but all values (variables) are NULLed since the model where I'm accessing `$this->agent` is passed through the CURL request.

I have a test controller **OUTBOUND** from which the CURL request is made to another controller named **INBOUND** for example.

Once the schema is validated and all checkings are passed with success, the **INBOUND** calls the following function `inbound()`:

```
public function inbound()
{
    // Load dependencies
    $this->load->library('user_agent');

    var_dump($this->agent);
    die;
}
```

and it returns me the following dump:

```
object(CI_User_agent)[28]
    public 'agent' => null
    public 'is_browser' => boolean false
    public 'is_robot' => boolean false
    public 'is_mobile' => boolean false
    public 'languages' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
    public 'charsets' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
    public 'platforms' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
    public 'browsers' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
    public 'mobiles' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
    public 'robots' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
    public 'platform' => string '' (length=0)
    public 'browser' => string '' (length=0)
    public 'version' => string '' (length=0)
    public 'mobile' => string '' (length=0)
    public 'robot' => string '' (length=0)
```

Is there any proper way to not loose these information after the CURL request is made, I'm mean in **INBOUND** controller?

**** **UPDATED** ****

Is it possible to solve this problem without need to tell the 3rd party to include these informations into their CURL request ?

Comment: What about setting flash data in outbound?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194795/the-curl-user-agent

Comment: @Tpojka - Outbound is used by 1000 of websites, who made a CURL request, telling them to include these data would take a lot of time and efforts

Comment: Maybe is beyond me, but can't tell more. I assumed visitor is approaching to let's say `http://localhost/outbound` and than after logic of controller he is redirected to `http://localhost/inbound` URL. I just thought, if that is situation, you could store flash data related to session and call it in `inbound`. But seems I was wrong. Can't tell more without seeing outbound controller.

Comment: I don't think its possible as the agent is sent in the http headers. If the header isn't set (as you say with curl the request would have to be built with the header specified) then it won't be available. Also as far as I know the agent only refers to clients (ie what browser on what device) and curl is server side so neither of those things exist