# Pasting url in browser returns json, curl returns 400 error

Tags: php, json, curl

I am creating a loyalty discount for a client, and they have api that will return JSON with discount data.

Now I know how I need to generate api link, and when I output it in my error log, and then paste it to browser or postman I get the JSON just fine. But when I try to fetch the JSON using curl I get 400 error

> Status 400: Request authentication failed

The curl part looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$json = json_decode( curl_exec( $ch ), true );

error_log(print_r($api_url, true));
error_log(print_r($json, true));

if ( curl_errno( $ch ) ) {
    wp_die( curl_error( $ch ) );
}

$httpcode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
curl_close( $ch );

if ( $httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300) {
    wp_die( $json );
} else {
    wp_die( 'httpcode: ' . $httpcode . ' ' . __( 'Probably entered the wrong data on option menu, or REST API not responsive' ) );
}
```

When I look at error log I can see the url that works when I paste it to postman or browser.

Now, the postman is set to `GET`, and when I tried to switch it to `POST` I got the same error. Postman returns headers

```
CONTENT-LENGTH → 238
```

I tried setting

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
```

before geting `curl_exec`, but I still get the same error.

Any way to see what could be wrong here?

Oh and I am generating the request using ajax. So user inputs their ID, and submit it to ajax and then I should check and return the json.

EDIT:

I've outputted the headers in my error log

```
[25-Oct-2016 12:07:53 UTC] Array
(
    [url] => this is the url
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 400
    [header_size] => 48
    [request_size] => 248
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.564651
    [namelookup_time] => 0.510374
    [connect_time] => 0.520541
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.52061
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 41
    [speed_download] => 72
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 41
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.564589
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 213.191.137.78
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    [local_port] => 60192
    [request_header] => GET /rest/api/v1/webshop/loycard/customer/the endpoint goes here HTTP/1.1
Host: the client host
Accept: */*


)
```

And when I look in the inspector of pasted link I have

```
GET /rest/api/v1/webshop/loycard/customer/the endpoint goes here HTTP/1.1
Host: the client host
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: hr-HR,hr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Comment: Looks like this script is using WP functions in it... are these cURL functions being used in the context of a WordPress function hooked to an ajax action, or does the script live on it's own, and just include `wp-blog-header.php`, or similar?

Comment: It's inside a ajax action. I will paste headers I get from browser and the ones returned by curl

Comment: Ok, I just googled and I shouldn't be using cURL in WordPress. There is a [wp_remote_get](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) function for this...

Comment: Thanks! I wonder - what do you know about the client's API server? Is it possible that cURL's lack of default User-Agent would throw it off? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194795/the-curl-user-agent

Comment: Could be it, I have the API documentation, but I don't have details on the server in there, only the docs about endpoints. the `wp_remote_get` did the trick, even though it's discouraged in WP VIP environment, but that doesn't concern me :D

Comment: Right-oh! Glad you figured it out. Btw - strong suspicion this was this issue: WP_Http - the class used by `wp_remote_get()` sets user-agent headers. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/class-http.php#L188

Comment: Something along that could be the issue, well I got it working so all is fine :)